# Guesstimate the number of windows in the Burj Khalifa

Tags: mathematics

> Guesstimate the number of windows in the Burj Khalifa

How should I proceed while solving this question?

Comment: number of floors * number of windows per floor?

Comment: I don't think it's that easy. Burj is not cylindrical in shape.

Comment: You might start with google *24,348 windows* :)

Comment: @Techidiot I know the answer. This question is about how I will guess the number...I want to guesstimate...I wrote that in the question right?

Comment: I think I've got a pretty close solution to how, though I definitely think it could be improved

Comment: DuckDuckGo! How close am I?

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a puzzle to me...

Answer (score 14):

This is by no means a perfect mathematical solution, but it gets pretty close and while it makes a lot of assumptions it works.

---

The Burj Khalifa has $163$ floors.

[image] Yes. 163. [Tom Cruise must have been shattered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27MYQ.jpg)

This would be easy to do if the Burj Khalifa was cylindrical but it isn't, because whoever heard of a cylindrical building? [Oh, wait...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uonuC.jpg)

[image]
[image]

We can see that every few floors up, a section ends making it thinner and thinner as altitude increases.

The picture on the right shows that there are approximately $10$ sections.

However this is for $2/3$ sides, so we can assume that if we multiply $10$ by $1.5$ (reciprocal) we can get the total amount of sections: $15$

If we take a rough estimate and assume that the sections stop equally, we can say that a section ends every $163/15$ $=$ approx $10$ floors. (Note here it is better to round down because the top few floors are very thin and will decrease the final answer)

So, if we count the windows on $1$ floor of a single section I get around $20$ windows (from a separate image of the bottom of the tower where it is clearer to see).

Now I have all the numbers I need: Floors = $163$, Sections = $15$, Windows per floor per section = $20$

The smallest section = $20$ windows per floor * $10$ floors = $200$ windows for smallest section.

The next section is $2$x as large = $400$ windows.

The next section is $3$x as large = $600$ windows.

Continuing like this for the $15$ sections gives

$${\begin{array}{rcl}\\\large{\text{200+400+600+800+1000+1200 ... 2200+2400+2600+2800+3000}}\\\end{array}}$$

And putting that into a calculator gives:

## $${\begin{array}{rcl}\\\Huge{\text{24000}}\\\end{array}}$$

Just $348$ windows off the actual amount of $24348$ windows*. Not bad for a guesstimate...

[image]

<sub>* based off @techidiots comment, which suggest he found that figure online</sub>